# Passing pointer-to-char in function: syntax error

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-pointer, pointer-to-array

My question is related to my previous post:

[explicit specialization: syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860944/explicit-specialization-syntax-error)

I am trying to pass arrays of pointer-to-chars as an argument to a function (which I will later incorporate to a specialized function from previous post), but I cannot get the syntax right.

The following were declared under main program:

```
char c0[30] = { "see if this works" };
char c1[30] = { "functions" };
char c2[30] = { "explicit specialization" };
char *d[] = { c0, c1, c2 };
```

the next line prints "functions " as I was expecting:

```
cout << "test print d[1] " << d[1] << endl;
```

The next step is to test whether I am able to return the character-array that I want to return, but my syntax is incorrect.  The following returns 's' (from c0) instead of an entire char-array:

function call:

```
cout << "string compare is " << compare2(*d, 3);
```

function declaration:

```
char compare2(char const arr2[], int n) {
    char temp;
    temp = arr2[0];

    return temp;
```

appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Oh never mind.  I figured it out :D

pointer declaration:

```
char *(d[]) = { c0, c1, c2 };
```

function call:

```
cout << "string compare is " << compare2(d, 3);
```

function definition:

```
char * compare2(char * const arr2[], int n) {
    char * temp;
    temp = *(arr2+2);

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: The pointer declaration, function call, and function signature were fine. You were dereferencing a char array when you didn't want to. Unless you were trying to do something much different than what you had been doing.

Comment: `char *d[] = ` and `char *(d[]) = ` are the same

Comment: `char *(d[])` looks very bad. Note that you're not using `n` in `compare2`. There's probably a reason you're passing it, right?

Comment: @JamesRoot Thanks.  The initial code was giving me a character in the character array - I was trying to return the entire (char) string.

Comment: @M.M Thanks.  I was desperately adding and removing characters from the code and forgot about this.  It was not compiling most of the times I changed it.

Comment: @erip Thanks.  'n' will later be used - the function is supposed to compare char-string lengths but I wanted to make sure that I am returning the correct array first.